# Pointwise convergence - $\frac{nx}{1+n \sin(x)}$ , $x \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Is anyone able to check if this is correct:

for $$f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+n \sin(x)} , x \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$$

Does this converge pointwise to $$ \frac{x}{\sin(x)}$$

I am unsure due to the fact that at $x=0$ that would be undefined,

yet

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{nx}{1+n \sin(x)} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x}{\frac{1}{n}+ \sin(x)} = \frac{x}{\sin(x)}$$

I am not sure what else to do further, or how to handle this for the case of $x= 0$ ?

Can it be used the fact that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{\sin(x)} = 1$$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $f_n(0)= 0/(1+0)=0$ for each $n$.

Comment: This I realised, but was unsure of what to say about the pointwise convergence for function

Comment: It converges to $f(x)=\cases{{x\over\sin x},& $0<x\le\pi/2$\cr 0, & $x=0$ }$.

Comment: got it, thanks. For some reason I concluded $f(x)$ had to take one value, and didn't think of hybrid functions

Comment: @pointwiseconvergence Just for the sake of clear terminology, such functions are called _piecewise functions_ ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already proved that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = \begin{cases}0 & x=0\\ \frac x{\sin x} & x \ne 0 \end{cases}$$
And this limit is indeed pointwise (as you can fix $x\ne 0$ and obtain the limit $\frac x{\sin x}$ and fix $x=0$ and obtain $f_n(0) = 0 \to 0$).

Furthermore because the $f_n$ are continuous for $x\in [0, \frac\pi2]$ and the limit function is discontinuous at $0$ (as you correctly asserted), you can also say that the convergence is *not* uniform.

Comment: Haha, this was the next exercise in my book, albeit an obvious one :P

Thanks for the answer,  I will accept it when the timer lets me.